# Can't add new asset catalog to Asset Library in Blender 3.5

Tags: asset-browser, settings, asset, library

After a drive failure I have had to upgrade to Windows 11 and reinstall Blender, version 3.5. I noticed that I can't add new asset catalogues:

[image]

When trying to add a new asset catalog, I get the text `Disabled: Asset catalogs cannot be edited in this asset library`

My current settings for my asset library are `User Library -> D:\blender\assetlibrary`

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Blender Version 3.5 the default displayed library is called *All*. This library is a concatenation of all your available libraries, so that all your assets are available in one place. It is however a read-only library, since it is automatically populated with the contents of all your other libraries.

The only library you can modify in the context of an opened blend file is called *Current File* :

[image]

Note the pen and paper icon that indicates you can modify this library.

If you want to change the default opened library on a new file, change the library to *Current File* and save the file as default in *File > Defaults > Save Startup File*.

See [this commit](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/7ba59c8a62) and [this commit](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/35e54b52e6) for more information. You can also read the [release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.5/Pipeline_Assets_IO) for the asset browser.

Comment: Solved! Thank you